# how to retrieve values of the map returned by jsonPath().getMap methods of rest assured

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

how to retrieve values of the map returned by jsonPath().getMap methods of rest assured
I am trying to get the response on below api in Map, which I am able to successfully get but when I try to access the value of key "id" in the below code, I get cast Error on line "String id = test.get("id");"

```
public void testRestAssured() {
        Response apiResponse = RestAssured.given().get("https://reqres.in/api/user/2");
        Map<String, String> test = apiResponse.jsonPath().getMap("data");
        System.out.println(test);
        String id = test.get("id");
        System.out.println("ID : " + id);
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I tried to do many things like

```
String id = test.get("id").toString();      
or
String id = String.valueOf(test.get("id"));
```

but nothing helped in resolution

api response is as follows

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "fuchsia rose",
        "year": 2001,
        "color": "#C74375",
        "pantone_value": "17-2031"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, it is working fine for me:

```
Response apiResponse = RestAssured.given().get("http://reqres.in/api/user/2");
Map<Object, Object> test = apiResponse.jsonPath().getMap("data");
System.out.println(test);
String id = test.get("id").toString();
System.out.println("ID : " + id);
```

The changes I have done is: change Map of (String, String) to Map (Object, Object) because we know that each key of map is string but value could be of any data type.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is

```
    Response apiResponse = RestAssured.given().get("http://reqres.in/api/user/2");
    Map<Object, Object> test = apiResponse.jsonPath().getMap("data");
    System.out.println(test);

    for (Object e : test.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(" Key is " + e + "  , value is " + test.get(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try this:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

JsonPath extractor = JsonPath.from(apiResponse.toString());
String id = extractor.getString("data.id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define Object for map value. Because your json values are different types (String and int).

```
    // define Object type for map values

    Map<String, Object> test = apiResponse.jsonPath().getMap("data");
   
    // use casting for assigning

    int id = (int) test.get("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to make from your response map object?

If not you can use this one:

```java
String id = RestAssured.given().get("https://reqres.in/api/user/2")
             .then().extract().jsonPath().getString("data.id");
```